# AKS Network Policy: Why the "host" could not be resolved when adding network policy?

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have kubernetes Cluster deployed on Azure (AKS). On that cluster i have a wordpress deployed with helm. And Azure mariadDB which is accessible to Worpress via External Service Object:

My External service look like :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql 
  namespace: app 
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: somename.mariadb.database.azure.com
```

I defined network policy on my Wordpress chart. And the `values.yml` look like:

```
# Azure MariaDB infos
externalDatabase:
  #host: 10.0.4.68   # IT WORKS FINE WHEN I PUT MARIADB IP
  host: mysql # IT DOES NOT WORK WHEN I PUT EXTERNAL SERVICE OBJECT NAME NOR THE FOLLOWING ENFPOINT: somename.mariadb.database.azure.com
  port: 3306
  database: bitnami_wordpress
networkPolicy:
  enabled: true
  ingressRules:
    accessOnlyFrom:
      enabled: true
    customRules: 
    - {} 
  egressRules:
    customRules:
      - to:
          - ipBlock:
              cidr: 10.0.4.64/28 # THE VSUBNET OF MARIADB DATABASE
        ports:
          - protocol: TCP
            port: 3306
```

When i replace `externalDatabase.host` with the IP of MariaDB it works fine. But when replace it with the external service object name (ie: `mysql` which is the 1st manifest) or with the endpoint (ie: `somename.mariadb.database.azure.com` ) i got the follwing error:

```
wordpress 15:35:09.41 DEBUG ==> Executing SQL command:
SELECT 1
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown server host 'somename.mariadb.database.azure.com' (-3)
wordpress 15:35:34.43 DEBUG ==> Executing SQL command:
```

PS: the above error is when i set `externalDatabase.host` to `somename-dev.mariadb.database.azure.com` which is the same error as when `externalDatabase.host`set to `mysql`

Any help please